# Preserving quantities under linear transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, classical-mechanics, invariant-theory

Find the linear transformation between two coordinate systems on a two-dimensional flat surface that preserves the quantity $s^2 = x^2 − y^2$.

I can't figure out what it means to "preserve" this quantity and how to solve the question. Question from my classical mechanics class.

Comment: You have to find a linear transformation $(x',y')=(ax+by,cx+dy)$ such that $x'^2-y'^2=x^2-y^2$.

Comment: @Gonçalo So the identity transformation would work right? Otherwise I assume I'd have to use the hyberbolic rotation matrix?

Comment: Yes, it would, but I believe that you must find all linear transfomations that preserve the form of $s^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint by way of an analogy: If $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ (the squared distance from the origin), then $r^2$ is preserved under any rotation, e.g.
$$
R_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$

So if we define new coordinates $(X, Y)$ by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix} 
= R_\theta 
\begin{pmatrix}
X \\ Y 
\end{pmatrix}, 
$$
then
$$
r^2 = x^2 + y^2 
= (X\cos\theta - Y\sin\theta)^2 + (X\sin\theta + Y\cos\theta)^2 
= X^2 + Y^2 
= R^2.
$$

You can think of this geometrically as mapping a point on the circle of radius $r$ to a new point on the circle with the same radius.

For your exercise, replace the circles by hyperbolas. What transformation maps points on a given hyperbola $s^2 = x^2 - y^2$ to another point on the same hyperbola?